# which React component should i use with parameters?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

> This is my MainLayout Component:

```
export const MainLayout = ({header, content, footer}) =>(
<div>
    <header>
        {header}
    </header>
    <main>
        <Paper style={contentStyle} zDepth={1}>
            {content}
        </Paper>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <Paper style={contentStyle}>
            {footer}
        </Paper>
    </footer>
</div>);
```

> This is my MainLayout with React.Component

```
export class MainLayout extends React.Component{
constructor({header, content, footer}){
    super();
    this.header = header;
    this.content = content;
    this.footer = footer;
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <header>
                {this.header}
            </header>
            <main>
                <Paper style={contentStyle} zDepth={1}>
                    {this.content}
                </Paper>
            </main>
            <footer>
                <Paper style={contentStyle}>
                    {this.footer}
                </Paper>
            </footer>
        </div>
    )
}}
```

when i use my first MainLayout Component all the header, content and footer work properly. I want to add **constructor()** and **componentDidMount()** but i can't! So, I'm trying to use ES6 class (React.Component of my second MainLayout) with **construcor()** I add 3 parameters. It's work for me! **But, when I link to other pages, the content is not respond.** I mean the old content still the same. Unitl i refresh the page and then Content is changed!

> So can you tell me if I made mistakes with creating these component?
>   Thanks so much your helping :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stateless components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions) (`const mainLayout = () => {}`) are just functions, so they lack constructors and life-cycle methods.

When you're using [ES6 class component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes), all attributes are attached to `this.props`. You don't have to add them manually to `this`. Whenever a prop changes, react will re-render the component.

```
export class MainLayout extends React.Component{
constructor(props){ // not strictly needed, but since you want a constructor anyway...
    super(props);
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <header>
                {this.props.header} // all props are bound to this.props
            </header>
            <main>
                <Paper style={contentStyle} zDepth={1}>
                    {this.props.content} // all props are bound to this.props
                </Paper>
            </main>
            <footer>
                <Paper style={contentStyle}>
                    {this.props.footer} // all props are bound to this.props
                </Paper>
            </footer>
        </div>
    )
}}
```

If you don't want to refer to `this.props` all the time, you can use destructuring, like you did in the stateless component:

```
export class MainLayout extends React.Component{
constructor(props){ // not strictly needed, but since you want a constructor anyway...
    super(props);
}
render(){
    const { header, content, footer } = this.props; // destructure this.props to consts

    return(
        <div>
            <header>
                {header}
            </header>
            <main>
                <Paper style={contentStyle} zDepth={1}>
                    {content}
                </Paper>
            </main>
            <footer>
                <Paper style={contentStyle}>
                    {footer}
                </Paper>
            </footer>
        </div>
    )
}}
```

btw - where does contentStyle comes from?

Comment: I add Paper style to Content :D
THANKS SO MUCH! This Really helps me!

Comment: Welcome. Shouldn't `contentStyle` be one of the props?

Comment: yes! Now i have problem with it. I want to the contentStyle automatically changed when the screen is responsive (Large, Medium and Small). or maybe you want me to put the contentStyle inside Constructor? I am sorry if i don't get your point :D

Comment: It depends on where you want to put the responsiveness logic.

Comment: i haven't got any answers from my new question :(

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36637815/how-to-automatically-change-contentstyle-when-the-screen-is-responsive